# postfix not sending email automatically

Tags: email, postfix-mta, centos6

I am attempting to use postfix to send emails from an application. Right now when I send an email using mailx it appears that the email gets to the queue but it doesn't actually send until I flush the queue manually.

Can anyone tell me how I can get postfix to send any emails that are in the queue automatically?

```
Right now my test is:
mailx user@domain.com
subject: some test
this is sometest
ctl-d
```

When I look at the queue using postqueue or mailq the system tells me the mail queue is empty. But as soon as I flush the queue I the relay server receives the email and they get to my inbox.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you run `service --status-all` does it show postfix as running ie a `[ + ]` next to it ?

Comment: Please post the log lines generated by postfix before you manually flush the queue.

Comment: @andrew I didn't find postix in the listing at all when I ran service --status-all

Comment: @clement89 I assume you mean post what is generated in the log before flushing the queue? Just want to make sure I post the right thing.

Comment: At the following URL you can see what is in /var/log/maillog. This is just after restarting the postfix service this morning (just on a whim). 

http://pastebin.com/4zb8D5Mv

I created an email using mailx on the command line. 
mailx myemail@mycompany.org
subject: this is a postfix test
test beeeep
ctrl-d

mailq command show the queue as being empty just after I finished this email.

Comment: The maillog is fine. The mail is sent to `192.168.1.55` successfully. btw how do u flush your queue?

Comment: I flush my queue by typing postqueue -f. I have not run this command yet and I still have not not received that test email.

Comment: Well I don't know what happened but everything appears to be working fine for what I need. While sending an email using mailx doesn't send me an email unless I flush the queue, the application for which I needed postfix for is actually sending me emails without issue. Very strange but at this point glad that its working.